# Each coadjoint orbit of a compact connected Lie group $G$ admits a $G$-invariant generalized complex structure

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, lie-groups, lie-algebras, sg.symplectic-geometry

I am looking for a proof or counterexample for following assertion

> Each [coadjoint orbit](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/coadjoint+orbit) of a compact connected Lie group $G$ admits
>   a [$G$-invariant generalized complex structure](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0712.2627.pdf) (In sense of Nigel
>   Hitchin)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In 1950s A. Borel, R. Bott, J. L. Koszul, F. Hirzebruch et al. investigated the coadjoint orbits as complex
homogeneous manifolds. It was proven that each coadjoint orbit of a compact
connected Lie group $G$ admits a canonical G-invariant complex structure and the
only (within homotopies) $G$-invariant Kählerian metrics.

Reference: Bott R. The Geometry and Representation Theory of Compact Lie Groups, In: Representation
Theory of Lie Groups, London Mathematical Society Lecture Note Series,
Cambridge Univ. Press, 34 (1979) 65–90.

Comment: Dietrich Burde , But what about G-invariant generalized complex structure ? this is the question

Comment: I thought that complex and symplectic structures are two canonical examples giving generalized complex structures ?